# Intranet 600 users

Tags: cms, intranet

Looking for an Intranet solution to replace custom one built about a decade ago. Traditionally the organization has used the .NET stack and the dev team is most comfortable within that ecosystem. Would prefer to self-host but cloud-based is an option if the case is compelling. We have around 600 users/employees. The budget is fairly open, if there are discounts for non-profit status that would be icing on the cake!

Features:

- CMS editor
- File Management and versioning
- Active Directory Integration
- Customization or Themes
- User Profiles Approval Workflows (content must be approved before being published)
- Event Calendar
- Strong Search capabilities
- Plugin or Extension support

Nice To Haves:

- Blogging functionality
- Knowledgebase,forum or wikis
- Chat
- Customizable per user (user can select a theme, personal links, login page based on department, etc..)
- Awards/trophy system

The 2 that have come up consistently are [Igloo](https://www.igloosoftware.com/) and [DNN/Evoq](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/products/evoq-content) . Experiences with those also welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend **SharePoint Server 2016**.

The pricing can be quite steep but it will do everything you specify.

If you do not want to have user pages you could use **SharePoint Foundation** which is free.

SharePoint has file storage and some basic versioning control (checkin, and checkout) and with the server version you can have personal user pages. It does not have an awards system but I am sure that you would probably be able to implement it with a plugin. It is developed by Microsoft so you can develop plugins with C# if you need your development team to develop anything. It does not have chat by default but there are several chat plugins.